# Macro script to search specific text in a column where row keep changing

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will go through a column Let say Column A and in that column there is a row that contains a text " the cpu utilization is xx%" and from that line if the macro can strip the "XX%" and put this value into a new sheet anywhere in the same workbook.

Please note that row is not fixed the text remains same but rows will change and column remain same

```
Sub Test() 
Dim ws As Worksheet 
Dim rFind As Range 
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2") 
Set rFind = Range("A:A").Find("*TOTAL*", LookIn:=xlValues) 
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B11") = rFind 
End Sub
```

Comment: please share your efforts ! SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 1):

This was a pretty easy one so I just did it real quick.

```
Sub FindPhrase()
Dim i As Long, searchCol As Long, dCell As Range, ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet

'column A
searchCol = 1

'output cell
Set dCell = ws.Range("B1")

'search through cells in specified column
For i = 1 To ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, searchCol).End(xlUp).Row
    If InStr(ws.Cells(i, searchCol), "The cpu utilization is ") > 0 And InStr(ws.Cells(i, searchCol), "%") > 0 Then
        dCell.Value = CDbl(Replace(Mid(ws.Cells(i, searchCol), InStr(ws.Cells(i, searchCol), "%") - 2, 2), "%", ""))
        Exit For
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks J.Fox I am not code expert, but i tried following Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFind As Range
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rFind = Range("A:A").Find("*TOTAL*", LookIn:=xlValues)
    
    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("B11") = rFind
     
End Sub

Comment: But it does the job but I was not able to extract the "XX%" and the other problem was that it worked only once that that picked the value and pasted in Cell but if you run the macro again it after deleting the value it was giving blank